# MSSQL 2008 - new tables do not show columns when using intelliSense

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

After creating new tables in MSSQL 2008, the intellisense list never displays updated tables or table names and columns. (Am using server management studio when this happens).

Does anyone know how to refresh this information in sql 2008 without closing the SQL server management studio 2008 and logging back in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In management studio, go to Edit Menu -> Intellisense -> RefreshLocalCache, click on this and it will reload the cached copy of the schema and update the intellisense.

```
  Key commands - CTRL+SHIFT+R
```

Comment: perfect, I just found it myself and was coming back to close the question, but will reward you for the answer, cheers mate

Comment: Wow, never even knew that was there. I always wondered if there was some way to do that.